# fixture 'recommendation_new_t' not found

Tags: python, api, pytest

Hi I am using the below function

```
def test_calculate_debt_free_date(recommendation_new_t):
    debt_free_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+recommendation_new_t)
    year = debt_free_date.year
    month = debt_free_date.month
    return "{0}/{1}".format(month, year)
```

and now using the function in other function as below

```
debt_free_month = test_calculate_debt_free_date(ap_rq[i]['recommendation_new_t'])
```

while running my test I am getting below error
fixture 'recommendation_new_t' not found, can anyone help here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `recommendation_new_t` as a [`pytest.fixture()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) either inside the same file your tests reside in or in a separate file called `conftest.py`.

The fixture can be defined like this:

```python
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def recommendation_new_t():
    return # something useful
```

Once it's defined, you can simply use `recommendation_new_t` as an argument in your test functions.

Comment: your forgot the @ sign when decorating the function

Answer (score 0):

Methods that start with `test_` are defined as test methods. Parameters to these methods are considered fixtures, and are special functions that will be evaluated and the result will be passed to the test.

If you want to re-use a function across test, don't prefix it with `test_`.

```
def calculate_debt_free_date(recommendation_new_t):
    debt_free_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+recommendation_new_t)
    year = debt_free_date.year
    month = debt_free_date.month
    return "{0}/{1}".format(month, year)

...

def test_your_actual_test():
    debt_free_month = calculate_debt_free_date(ap_rq[i]['recommendation_new_t'])
```

However, it seems kind of weird to perform active dynamic calculations in your tests, as you usually would want to have known input and known output. If that code replicates the code that you have in the function you're testing, you're not really testing anything other than that the code is similar in both places.

Comment: this doesn't address the error OP is facing. the error he is getting is related to fixtures and his test not being able to locate the fixture.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, however, both the solutions work for me using a reusable function without test initials in the name and defining fixture as below.